# Convert an existing debian systemd init script to Ubuntu 18.04 compatible version?

Tags: scripts, startup, systemd

I need to create an /etc/init.d startup script for `msmtpd` and thought it would be a good idea to convert an existing one from Debian to Ubuntu 18.04. What should be done to properly convert [this .deb's](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/msmtp-mta) ([download](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/msmtp-mta/download)) init.d script to work properly with Ubuntu?

For quicker reference, here are the two content files that seem to have relevance:

- [/etc/init.d/msmtpd](https://p153.p0.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/YEuvZgEQ/msmtpd)
- [/lib/systemd/system/msmtpd.service.app](https://p153.p0.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/RBu0l5p5/msmtpd.service)

A really helpful bonus would be to also implement `stop` and `restart`...